# How to run same function simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x

So basically everytime i press P, i would like this function to run.
Right now it runs once function has finished. How do i make the function start another process of itself so i can run them simultaneously?

```
import os, keyboard, asyncio
from multiprocessing import Process

async def function():
    print('function started')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('function stopped')

while True:
    if keyboard.read_key() == "p":
        print("p")

    running_tasks = [Process(target=asyncio.run(function()))]
    
    for running_task in running_tasks:
        running_task.start()
    for running_task in running_tasks:
        running_task.join()
```

Comment: Remove join command. It places your async process to main thread.

Comment: still same issue, it keeps waiting until the function has been ran, then i can run it again...

Comment: You're creating a list of only one process to run at a time. How many did you actually intend to run at a time? Also, it looks like you're calling your function immediately instead of having `asyncio.run()` run it.

Comment: Also also, why are you using async inside the separate process? Most likely you want to pick one of the two—either asyncio, or multiprocessing—to make your function run simultaneously. If you really need to use both, please [edit] your question to explain why.

Comment: @DanGetz Hey, thanks for replying! I am planning to run few functions like this simultaneously... The real function is a long one, so i am not posting the code here. I do not have asyncio in the real function, i just wanted to know how to do it, is the asyncio the problem here? i gotta test...

Comment: i mean i am planning on running 1 function few times simultaneously*

Comment: The right way to run a multiprocessing function along with asyncio is probably going to depend on what your function actually does. What results from the function do you want in your main process? Maybe this other question's answers will help you? https://stackoverflow.com/q/21159103/3004881

Comment: You shouldn't need multiprocessing at all just to run something with `asyncio.sleep` simultaneously, though.