# streamlit does not work with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, streamlit

I am working on a project in which I am using streamlit, it works fine except of that when I add multiprocessing to the code, it does not work (the streamlit part), so I starting debugging and stripping my code down to get to the bottom of it, and I reached to a very simple code, and it does not work, anyone has any idea why it does not work please? Here is the code:

```
import streamlit as st
import multiprocessing as mp

def fun():
    st.write('Testing streamlit with multiprocessing')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = mp.Process(target=fun)
    p1.start()
    p1.join()
```

It runs but not will be displayed on the browser, and I am using `streamlit run file.py` from the command prompt to run it

**UPDATE:**
BTW, if I move the MTing from the code, it runs well, like below:

```
import streamlit as st
import multiprocessing as mp

def fun():
    st.write('Testing streamlit with multiprocessing')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fun()
```

Comment: I'd invert the way you're doing this and generally have a wrapper spawn the subprocesses and then gather the results up to present to the streamlit app rather than having any subprocess attempt to write to it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What kind of problems (if any) would there be combining asyncio with multiprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159103/what-kind-of-problems-if-any-would-there-be-combining-asyncio-with-multiproces)

Comment: First, I am not sure if I understood your first comment clearly, would appreciate if you can put small code, second I actually have 3 different processes (functions), one for capturing, one for calculations, and the this for streamlit, the problem is when I add the streamlit into the MPing, if the first 2 are running on their own, everything is fine, and as you can see in my sample, nothing much to gather and present, it is simply printing, finally, the `asyncio` is not really a multiprocessing, so this is not what I am looking for, but thanks for your response anyway, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

So what I suspect is happening is that Streamlit is running in the main process which means your child processes cannot interact with it directly. You can use a shared memory object like a `Queue` to communicate between the child processes (functions) and the main process (Streamlit).

Based on your comment in the chat, here's how you could structure your code:

```
import streamlit as st
import multiprocessing as mp

# Function to capture data
def capture(q1):
   # Capture data and put it into q1
   pass

# Function to do calculations on captured data
def calculate(q1, q2):
   # Retrieve data from q1, do calculations, and put results 
   # into q2
   pass

# Function to display results in Streamlit app
def display(q2):
   while True:
         # Retrieve results from q2 and display them in 
         # Streamlit app
         results = q2.get()
         st.write(results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
# Create Queues for communication between processes
q1 = mp.Queue()
q2 = mp.Queue()

# Create and start child processes
p1 = mp.Process(target=capture, args=(q1,))
p2 = mp.Process(target=calculate, args=(q1, q2))
p1.start()
p2.start()

# Start display loop in the main process
display(q2)
```

Comment: Hi Tony, I actually moved on with this, I think streamlit is not compatible with Multiprocessing, because I have created a simple app that only prints (Hello) and it did not work, I have posted the question on their community pages and no response, so I am working on plotly dash, which I started to like, even though a new phase of learning. But thanks anyway

Comment: You can definitely run Streamlit with multiprocessing. I do it all the time with no issues. Streamlit has a help chat where they explain how to do it.